# Export ArcGrid Raster to Esri file geodatabase on MacOS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, raster-conversion

I have downloaded [this](https://landfire.cr.usgs.gov/Website/distreq/RequestSummary.jsp?TID=AT02&ID=1900&IDDESC=California&PL=FHW08HZ,F1S08HZ,) dataset, what I believe is an ArcGrid Raster, from [this](https://www.landfire.gov/viewer/) site. However, I ideally would like the data to be in a file geodatabase format so that I can access it using GeoPandas in Python. I am on a Mac and don't have access to a Windows machine, so I don't have the ability to export this in ArcMap as the tutorial that I found [here](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-export-raster-to-esri-geodatabase-file/) suggests.

Is there a way I can convert this without using ArcMap / using software on MacOS?

Comment: It's curious that USGS uses the format name "ArcGRID_with_attribs" since no such name exists.  There is an ArcGIS (ArcInfo) Grid format, but this is a raster, which cannot be loaded into  (or out of) file geodatabase without ArcGIS, and it cannot be manipulated with GeoPandas (which works with vectors). GDAL can probably read a grid raster, and numpy manipulate it. You'd have to convert the raster to vector before using it with GeoPandas.

Comment: If you want to work with this raster in python on a Mac change the download options to download a geotiff and then work with it using GDAL, numpy, rasterio, or other raster libraries. Skip the file geodatabase and GeoPandas - those are tools for working with vector data, not raster data.

Comment: @Vince I wonder if "ArcGRID_with_attribs" is an integer grid that has had a raster attribute table built for it.

Comment: @PolyGeo No RAT, just a dBase-III file (.dbf) with what the RAT would have contained

Comment: I've never used GeoPandas so I might be completely wrong but I thought Geopanadas was just for vector data? So even if you imported the raster into a file geodatabase you would not be able to use it anyway?